# What does Deprecated mysql_connect() mean?

Tags: php, mysql

Problem in my php code

```
function connect()
{
    $connector = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connector);
    if($connector)
    {
        if(mysql_select_db("news",$connector))
            return true;
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

if(connect())
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM category";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC) )
        {
        ?> <li><a href=""><?php echo $row['catName']; ?></a></li>
        <?php
        }
    }   
}
```

my php version is 5.5.12 & use wamp server 2.5
My code tells me this:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO & in php

What does that mean and how can I handle it?

Comment: The error is self-explanotary : the mysql driver is now deprecated, use mysqli or pdo to connect to your database. Like mysqli_connect for exemple :) (note the "i")

Comment: i use :
$connector = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","news");
$sql="SELECT * FROM akhbar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result = $connector->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["title"]. " " . $row["matn"]. "<br>";
           }
 it dont worked !!

Answer (score 2):

The error is pointing the matter well

> > **Deprecated: mysql_connect()**: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO & in php

## [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)(link)

**Error in php.net**

> > This extension **was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0**, and it **was removed in PHP 7.0.0**. Instead, the ***MySQLi*** or ***PDO_MySQL*** extension should be used.

Use

1. [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
2. [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

As well as [per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525279/deprecated-mysql-connect-the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-remov#comment56792052_34525279)

> > You are conflicting **MySQL** and **MySQLi**. **MySQL** and **MySQLi** are two different Methods

Comment: @HosseinBustanchi accept this if helpfull